# How to scrape content from HTML using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm a bit of a VBA nube so hopefully you can assist with this. I'm trying to pull $66,749.17 from the following element:

```
<div class="priceValue">$66,749.17</div>
```

The following VBA script shows the core functions I'm using to pull the information:

```
Set doc = ie.Document 

MsgBox doc.getElementsByClassName("priceValue")
```

However, the message box only returns [ObjectHTMLdivElement], which isn't a surprise given that the function is getting elements rather than contents/text.  I have tried experimenting with things like innertext etc, but I can't seem to get them working.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of matches, so to get the content of the first match (assuming there is at least one match) -

```vb
MsgBox doc.getElementsByClassName("priceValue")(0).innerText
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim :)

Comment: @JHARR I would like to highlight also that `getElementsByClassName` will return a collection **even** if there's no element found so you should do a check first to see if there are any elements in the collection (e.g. `If doc.getElementsByClassName("priceValue").Length <> 0 Then` before attempting to do anything with the collection.